# FFmpeg transparent PNG black outline issue

Tags: ffmpeg, outline

I'm encoding a video with a transparent PNG using ffmpeg. I noticed there's a slight black outline surrounding the image. Is there any way to remove it?

Output image:
[image]

Transparent PNG sample:
[image]

My ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -ss 0.0 -t 8.5 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\6.mp4 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\text_and_emoji.png -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#18ffff[0v];[1:v]scale=556.24744:141.41884[1v];[0v][1v]overlay=(W-w)/2-(W/2-325.33328):(H-h)/2-(H/2-567.7075):enable='between(t,0.0,8.5)' -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -g 75 -r 20 -preset ultrafast -strict experimental C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\test.mp4
```

**Last edit 1:**

I tried using without `[1:v]scale=556.24744:141.41884[1v]`, the output still have the slight outline

Sample output:
[image]

Sample code:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -ss 0.0 -t 8.5 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\white.mp4 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\text_and_emoji.png -filter_complex [0:v]scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#18ffff[0v];[0v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2-(W/2-325.33328):(H-h)/2-(H/2-567.7075):enable='between(t,0.0,8.5)' -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -strict experimental C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\test.mp4
```

**Last edit 2:**

I tried another one with added `alpha=premultiplied` with latest ffmpeg version. It somehow removed the outline, but the quality of the picture reduced alot till it seems like it's pixelated. Plus. there's another unknown white layer at the back of the image.

Output video
[image: output video]

Sample code:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\ffmpeg-20180102-57d0c24-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg -y -ss 0.0 -t 8.5 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\white.mp4 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\text_and_emoji.png -filter_complex [0:v]scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#00ffff[0v];[1:v]scale=480:120[1v];[0v][1v]overlay=(W-w)/2-(W/2-325.33328):(H-h)/2-(H/2-567.7075):alpha=premultiplied:enable='between(t,0.0,8.5)' -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\test.mp4
```

**Latest edit 3:**

As suggested by @Mulvya, I combined his code with `alpha=premultiplied` and it seems alot better now, with very slight black outline (almost not visible)

Output video:
[image: Output video]

Sample code:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\ffmpeg-20180102-57d0c24-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg -y -ss 0.0 -t 8.5 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\white.mp4 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\text_and_emoji.png -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#18ffff[0v];[1:v]premultiply=inplace=1,scale=480:120[1v];[0v][1v]overlay=(W-w)/2-(W/2-325.33328):(H-h)/2-(H/2-567.7075):alpha=premultiplied:enable='between(t,0.0,8.5)':format=rgb,format=yuv420p -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\test.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in the overlay filter, since fixed. Alter your filtergraph to to this,

```
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#18ffff[0v];[1:v]premultiply=inplace=1,scale=556.24744:141.41884[1v];[0v][1v]overlay=(W-w)/2-(W/2-325.33328):(H-h)/2-(H/2-567.7075):enable='between(t,0.0,8.5)':format=rgb,format=yuv420p"
```

You'll need a FFmpeg version from after Dec 16 2017 for this.

Comment: thanks for the solution. It somehow removes the outline, but the quality of the image reduced alot till it seems like it's pixelated. Plus. there's another unknown white layer at the back of the image. I attached a screenshot in my main thread question.

Comment: I added with `alpha=premultiplied` and it seems alot better now, with very slight black outline (almost not visible). I attached another screenshot there. However, if i dun add `alpha=premultiplied`, it will show the black outline.

Comment: though an old answer, I am using this solution but, as a result, the overlay output is brighter than the input background, even if the overlayed image is completely 100% transparent. Do you know why or how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This occured to me due to loss of color definition while using the overlay filter.

The default format of the overlay filter is `yuv420`.

The `yuv420` format will reduce your color definition for increased transmission time. Changing the format to `rgb` or `yuv444` will use full chroma fixing the issue of black outline issue occuring.

> YUV is a color space typically used as part of a color image pipeline.
> It encodes a color image or video taking human perception into
> account, allowing reduced bandwidth for chrominance components,
> thereby typically enabling transmission errors or compression
> artifacts to be more efficiently masked by the human perception than
> using a "direct" RGB-representation. However, YUV 4:2:2 and YUV 4:2:0
> subsampling implements less resolution for chroma information than for
> luma information, resulting in loss of color definition.