# FFmpeg: Removing black outline on overlay after alphamerge

Tags: ffmpeg

Similar question: [FFmpeg transparent PNG black outline issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144440/ffmpeg-transparent-png-black-outline-issue)

When using FFmpeg to create a GIF from an mp4, masking the video using alphamerge and a PNG-mask, and overlaying a circle outline, black lines occur on both the video and the circle in the final GIF.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144440/ffmpeg-transparent-png-black-outline-issue), some suggestions are made to add `alpha=premultiplied` and `format=rgb,format=yuv420p` in the overlay-filter. This removes the black line (on the circle), but the masking from `alphamerge` no longer works.

Filter used which generates black outlines:

```
[0][1]alphamerge[merged];
[merged][2:v]overlay=
    format=auto:
    alpha=premultiplied[withCircleOverlay];
[withCircleOverlay]scale=${size}x${size}[scaled];
[scaled]split[s0][s1];
[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=on:transparency_color=ffffff[p];
[s1][p]paletteuse
```

Filter used which removes outlines, but also cropping:

```
[0][1]alphamerge[merged];
[merged][2:v]overlay=
    alpha=premultiplied:
    format=rgb,format=yuv420p[withCircleOverlay];
[withCircleOverlay]scale=${size}x${size}[scaled];
[scaled]split[s0][s1];
[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=on:transparency_color=ffffff[p];
[s1][p]paletteuse
```

Command used:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -i mask.png -i circle.png -filter_complex <filter> output.gif
```

What I've tried:

- Changing the format-parameter on overlay to a lot of different values.
- Changing the order of the filters.
- Playing around with running multiple ffmpeg-passes: First doing the merging, saving this to a file, and then adding the circle afterwards. I think this in principle should work if I tinker with it enough.

Are there any ways to get around this issue?

**Image with black outlines**

[image: Image with black outline]

**Image without outline, but also without alphamerge cropping**

[image: Image without outline, but also without alphamerge cropping]

Answer (score 1):

How about `unpremultiply` filter?

Try adding `unpremultiply=inplace=1` somewhere.
Maybe after the `alphamerge`, or before the `split`, or... somewhere nice.

AND remove the `alpha=premultiplied` parameter from `overlay`.

---

My test result:

[image: Off/On alpha=premultiplied * Off/On unpremultiply=inplace=1]

- "Just Overlay": causes black outline (in other words border/boundary/fringe) on all sides of the front square.
- "Premultiplied Overlay": seems nice on the opaque background, but leaves the black outline on the transparent one, you know.
- "Unpremultiply Filter": **fine**.
- "Unpremultiply + Premultiplied": seems nice on the transparent background, but causes extra white outline on the opaque one.

Its bash script:
(Using `-loglevel warning` to keep stdout calm for multiple runs of ffmpeg and `-update 1 -frames:v 1` to output static images without warnings)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Prepare two resources
## back.png: left gold, right transparent
image_size=54
ffmpeg -loglevel warning \
  -f lavfi -i "color=color=gold:size=${image_size}x${image_size},
               format=rgba,
               crop=w=in_w/2:x=0,
               pad=w=in_w*2:x=0:color=black@0" \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y back.png
## front.png: a tilted cyan square
ffmpeg -loglevel warning \
  -f lavfi -i "color=color=cyan:size=36x36,
               format=rgba,
               pad=width=${image_size}:height=out_w:x=-1:y=-1:color=black@0,
               rotate=angle=30*PI/180:fillcolor=black@0" \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y front.png

# Overlay in 4 ways
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i back.png -i front.png \
  -filter_complex "[0] [1] overlay=format=rgb" \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y result0-just-overlay.png
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i back.png -i front.png \
  -filter_complex "[0] [1] overlay=format=rgb:alpha=premultiplied" \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y result1-pre.png
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i back.png -i front.png \
  -filter_complex "[1] unpremultiply=inplace=1 [front];
                   [0] [front] overlay=format=rgb" \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y result2-unpre.png
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i back.png -i front.png \
  -filter_complex "[1] unpremultiply=inplace=1 [front];
                   [0] [front] overlay=format=rgb:alpha=premultiplied" \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y result3-unpre-pre.png

# Enlarge with the Nearest Neighbor method and output combined result
scale=6
text_options="fontfile='C\:/Windows/fonts/arial.ttf':
              fontcolor=black:
              fontsize=28"
lf=$'\n'
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i result0-just-overlay.png \
                         -i result1-pre.png \
                         -i result2-unpre.png \
                         -i result3-unpre-pre.png \
  -filter_complex "
    [0] [1] [2] [3] xstack=grid=2x2,
                    scale=width=in_w*${scale}:height=-1:flags=neighbor,
                    drawtext=text='Just${lf}Overlay':
                             x=(main_w-text_w)/2-${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             y=(main_h-text_h)/2-${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             ${text_options},
                    drawtext=text='Premultiplied${lf}Overlay':
                             x=(main_w-text_w)/2+${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             y=(main_h-text_h)/2-${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             ${text_options},
                    drawtext=text='Unpremultiply${lf}Filter':
                             x=(main_w-text_w)/2-${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             y=(main_h-text_h)/2+${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             ${text_options},
                    drawtext=text='Unpremultiply${lf}+${lf}Premultiplied':
                             x=(main_w-text_w)/2+${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             y=(main_h-text_h)/2+${image_size}*${scale}/2:
                             ${text_options}
  " \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y results.png
```

I'm surprised that it works even though the intermediate file "front.png" *has* the black outline:

[image: front.png]

*Why...?*

TBH I don't know its detailed reasons/mechanisms.
I just met the same issue and fortunately found this `unpremultiply` filter.

---

And apparently, even this filter is not a panacea.

The below script *should* produce an image using at most 1 color (+ 1 alpha channel) because ffmpeg just draws gold text on the gold background:

```bash
color=gold
ffmpeg -loglevel warning \
  -f lavfi -i "color=color=${color}:size=100x100, format=rgba" \
  -f lavfi -i "nullsrc=size=100x100, format=rgba" \
  -filter_complex "[1] drawtext=text='A':
                                fontfile='C\:/Windows/fonts/arial.ttf':
                                fontcolor=${color}:
                                fontsize=90:
                                x=(main_w-text_w)/2:
                                y=(main_h-text_h)/2,
                       unpremultiply=inplace=1 [text];
                   [0] [text] overlay=format=rgb" \
  -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y text.png
```

[image: text.png]

But, it *actually* results in 6 colors (+ 1 alpha).

Let ffmpeg count the number of colors:

```bash
$ ffmpeg -i text.png -vf "palettegen, metadata=mode=print" -f null - 2>&1 \
> | grep '^\[Parsed_palettegen'
[Parsed_palettegen_0 @ 000001a2fb678c00] 6(+1) colors generated out of 6 colors; ratio=1.000000
```

Or just visualize where the pixels of different colors are, with `normalize` filter:

```bash
ffmpeg -i text.png -vf "normalize" -update 1 -frames:v 1 -y text-normalize.png
```

[image: text-normalize.png]

***Why...!?***

So, I think there are probably other ways that would be more perfect.
Exparts wanted.